# How to provide data in form of nodes and edges for echarts tree?

Tags: tree, echarts

In eCharts to visualize a tree you can use [this type of chart](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=tree-basic).

It accepts data in form of [json](https://github.com/apache/echarts/blob/master/test/data/flare.json) with possibly infinite depth, where every child node of every parent is placed literally in `children` property.

But I'd like to provide data in form of nodes + edges object, like the one echarts-graphs are expecting: [echarts graph](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=graph-label-overlap), [json input](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/data/asset/data/les-miserables.json).

Is it possible or I have to write a custom javascript function which will convert data from one form to another?

Comment: Its not possible. If you would specify the data in the graph like format there was no way to determine which is the root node.

Comment: I think numerous algorithms exist to determine if provided graph is a tree and it's root node, and all of them are pretty trivial comparing to those used by echarts to build even simplest visualizations. But thank you for pointing out it is not supported rn.